# How to change vs code python extension lib installation from ~/.local to another location

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I have a shared home folder that is really small, so using the default location for the python extension library causes uses of disk quota.

Is there a way to change this location from ~/.local to another location?

Comment: This may help https://superuser.com/questions/1449639/

Comment: Thanks this helped

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to install vs-code extensions only inside the workspace?](https://superuser.com/questions/1449639/is-there-a-way-to-install-vs-code-extensions-only-inside-the-workspace)